# Launch python script fullscreen on startup (Ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, python, fullscreen

I have a python program that I would like to automatically run after logging in. This shouldn't be much of a problem, however, I would like the terminal to be in fullscreen mode while running the program.

I'm using two shell scripts. The first one (*autostart.sh*) starts up a terminal in fullscreen mode and then runs the second script:

```
#!/bin/bash
gnome-terminal --full-screen -e /home/me/scripts/start_python.sh
```

The second script (*start_python.sh*) is supposed to run the actual python program:

```
#!/bin/bash
python3 /home/me/scripts/python_app.py
```

Unfortunately, my python program just quits without returning anything after a few seconds. However, if I run the python program or any of the two scripts directly from the terminal after cd-ing into their directory everything works fine. But as soon as I start my python program using an absolute path (like in the second shell script), things don't work out anymore.

Is there any way, to start that python program without cd-ing into its directory by hand? Or can the problem be solved by just moving eveything to different directory? Right now, both shell scripts and the python program are in the same directory (*/home/me/scripts*).

Comment: Shouldn't there be a `#` before the `!/bin/bash` in the second one?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, it's actually in my script, I just forgot it when I wrote my post. I've corrected it now.

Comment: How do you set it to start at boot? DE's autostart? `systemd`?

Comment: Also, you don't need two scripts -- just put `python3 /home/me...` after the `-e` in the first one.

Comment: When I use only one script with `-e python3 /home/...` it's only starting the python interpreter instead of running the program. So it kind of ignores what comes after `python3`.

And I used `gnome-session-properties` to setup the autostart.

Comment: What if you put some quotes around `python3 yourscript.py` so it knows it's one command?